# Why Flutter qr and barcode scan packages do not scan all of the barcodes I try?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-qrcode

Well, I have used multiple Flutter barcode scan pakcages, but could not find the proper one. The best I have tried was MobileScanner that was fast and mostly accurate, but it has one problem. When I hot restart the app my screen would black out and icon appears in the middle of the screen. Here you can see it:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bwH9h.jpg)
It fixes automatically when I go to other app and back to my app without closing it.

Can someone show me the best flutter barcode scanner package that can scan most of the barcode types and is fast also. Also it should start to work automatically like i do not have to press some button for it to start.

Note: barcode_scan2, barcode_scanner. I have used these also, but they do not fit to my criteria.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: try this once: https://pub.dev/packages/quick_qr

Answer (score 0):

Here`s what I am using

[qr_code_scanner](https://pub.dev/packages/qr_code_scanner)

[flutter_barcode_scanner](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_barcode_scanner)

Hope that helps

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).